# How to get the parent MenuBar of a JavaFX Menu

Tags: java, javafx, scenegraph

I have not been able to find API in the JavaFX `Menu` class that would allow me to retrieve the parent `MenuBar`. Any hints, including the usage of internal API are very welcome. (JavaFX 8)

Background: Usually any JavaFX `Node` can give you it's parent with the method `getParent()`. But since `Menu` and `MenuItem` do not inherit from `Node`, this possibility is not available. The `MenuItem` class (and therefore also the `Menu` class) has two similar methods:

- `getParentPopup()` to get a parent `ContentMenu`
- `getParentMenu()` to get a parent `Menu`

So I would have expected something like `getParentMenuBar()`, but it's not there.

EDIT: I just found the jira feature request for this API extension:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091154

Has anybody found a workaround for this?

Comment: Is your application built programatically or via FXML?

Comment: We use FXML for the largest part of the ui.

Answer (score 1):

I'd question why you need access going from Menu back to MenuBar, what problem are you trying to solve?

One possible approach is to use the [arbitrary properties map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getProperties--) on Node to store a reference from Menu to MenuBar as this example shows.

```
public class MenuToMenuBar extends Application {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        MenuBar bar = new MenuBar();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(bar));
        Menu menu = new Menu("Foo");

        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem("Baz");
        menu.getItems().add(menuItem);
        bar.getMenus().add(menu);

        // put a reference back to MenuBar in each Menu
        for (Menu each : bar.getMenus()) {
            each.getProperties().put(MenuBar.class.getCanonicalName(), bar);
        }

        menuItem.setOnAction((e) -> {
            // retrieve the MenuBar reference later...
            System.out.println(menuItem.getParentMenu().getProperties().get(MenuBar.class.getCanonicalName()));
        });
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I could solve the problem by building my own mapping. Since we use fxml, we would need to do some post processing : 1) walk the scene graph and find `MenuBar` instances, then 2) hook a listener on `MenuBar.getMenus()` to save the relationships. (If you are really interested in why I need this, we should go into a private discussion about that, otherwise it would clutter the question. Of course, we are also evaluating other possible solutions, all with their own deficiencies.)